# How to rebuild hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array with hashes:

```
arr = [{"name1"=>{"users"=>"{\"root\":{\"Name\":\"root\",\"Home\":\"/root\",\"Status\":\"Active\"},\"bee\":{\"Name\":\"bee\",\"Home\":\"/bee\",\"Status\":\"Active\"}}"}}, 
{"name2"=>{"users"=>"{\"root\":{\"Name\":\"root\",\"Home\":\"/root\",\"Status\":\"Active\"},\"alo\":{\"Name\":\"alo\",\"Home\":\"/alo\",\"Status\":\"Active\"}}"}}]
```

The value of the "users" key is a string and must be JSON-parsed, and next value of the root key also.

I want to get something like this:

```
arr = ["name1"=>{"root"=>{"Name"=>"root", "Home"=>"root", "Status"=>"Active"}, "bee"=>{"Name"=>"bee", "Home"=>"bee", "Status"=>"Active"}},
    "name2"=>{"root"=>{"Name"=>"root", "Home"=>"root", "Status"=>"Active"}, "alo"=>{"Name"=>"alo", "Home"=>"alo", "Status"=>"Active"}}]
```

So far I've tried:

```
arr.each do |item|

  item.each do |key, val|

    h[key] = val.values
  end
end
```

which produces a hash:

```
h = {{"name1"=>["{\"root\":{\"Name\":\"root\",\"Home\":\"/root\",\"Status\":\"Active\"},\"bee\":{\"Name\":\"bee\",\"Home\":\"/bee\",\"Status\":\"Active\"}}"], "name2"=>["{\"root\":{\"Name\":\"root\",\"Home\":\"/root\",\"Status\":\"Active\"},\"alo\":{\"Name\":\"alo\",\"Home\":\"/alo\",\"Status\":\"Active\"}}"]}}
```

How do I rebuild those hashes to get parsed values and delete the "users" keys from every hash?

Comment: So far I've done something like this:

Comment: So far I've done something like this:
`arr.each do |item|

        item.each do |key, val|
                val = val.values
                h[key] = val
        end
end`

and I got hash 

`h = {"name1"=>["{\"root\":{\"Name\":\"root\",\"Home\":\"/root\",\"Status\":\"Active\"},\"bee\":{\"Name\":\"bee\",\"Home\":\"/bee\",\"Status\":\"Active\"}}"], "name2"=>["{\"root\":{\"Name\":\"root\",\"Home\":\"/root\",\"Status\":\"Active\"},\"alo\":{\"Name\":\"alo\",\"Home\":\"/alo\",\"Status\":\"Active\"}}"]}`

Comment: @mia102aim include that above response as an edit to your post so that it has nice formatting.

Comment: I also recommend providing a simple example instead of the mess of json. It makes it harder to understand what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimum code, and the minimum input data (JSON). Anything beyond that wastes our time as we try to help you, so help us help you by doing your part.

Comment: Your desired result is invalid. You can't have an array containing bare key/value pairs. You can have `[{...}]`, because that's what Ruby is going to turn it into.

Comment: Looking at the input data further, it's not a good use of hashes. This sounds like an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)" where the creation of the hash needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would ask for the code you began with but I can see why you are at a loss, so here a way you could do this:

```
require 'json'

arr = [{"name1"=>{"users"=>"{\"root\":{\"Name\":\"root\",\"Home\":\"/root\",\"Status\":\"Active\"},\"bee\":{\"Name\":\"bee\",\"Home\":\"/bee\",\"Status\":\"Active\"}}"}}, 
{"name2"=>{"users"=>"{\"root\":{\"Name\":\"root\",\"Home\":\"/root\",\"Status\":\"Active\"},\"alo\":{\"Name\":\"alo\",\"Home\":\"/alo\",\"Status\":\"Active\"}}"}}]


arr.map! do |user|
  user.map do |key, value|
    h = JSON.parse(value["users"].gsub('/',''))
    Hash[key, h]
  end
end
```

Or, if you prefer the shorter version:

```
arr.map!{|user| user.map{|key, value| Hash[key, JSON.parse(value["users"].gsub('/',''))]}}
```

Which gives:

```
[
  [{"name1"=>{"root"=>{"Name"=>"root", "Home"=>"root", "Status"=>"Active"}, "bee"=>{"Name"=>"bee", "Home"=>"bee", "Status"=>"Active"}}}], 
  [{"name2"=>{"root"=>{"Name"=>"root", "Home"=>"root", "Status"=>"Active"}, "alo"=>{"Name"=>"alo", "Home"=>"alo", "Status"=>"Active"}}}]
]
```

The `Hash[key, value]` lets you map a new Hash with a key value pair.

The extra `gsub` is because in your wanted result you omitted this slash while it's not part of the JSON encoding so it isn't removed with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Thanks! But I've done something like that
`arr.each do |item|

      item.each do |key, val|
              h[key] = JSON.parse(val['systemusers'])
      end
end`
It works but produces a hash. What should I change in this code to get an array?